# How can I reverse "action.KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys("N").Perform();" in C#, Seleium/Appium/Visual Studio

Tags: selenium, appium, keystroke

I am testing uploading from file explorer window that has been opened via web browser application - for some reason it can find the open window but can't find File name field and doesn't actually click the Open button (despite passing that step).. As a result I have had to use alt + N to select the File name field, which is all well and good, but that results in disabling my keyboard for all other apps.

I presumed that I would only need to do a KeyUp on the alt button as there is no equivalent for the N key, which is obviously sent using SendKeys method... The code below DOES run, but it is far from ideal if I'm going to have to keep coding key strokes that I can't reverse unless manually...

```
        if (open != null)
        {
            Actions action = new Actions(session);
            session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            action.KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys("N").Perform();
            action.KeyUp(Keys.Alt).SendKeys("19th December 1932 (2).xlsx").Perform();
            action.KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys("o").Perform();
            action.KeyUp(Keys.Alt).Perform();
```

Comment: I found a workaround:  if (openPC != null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                SelectDirectoryPathFromDD(dirPath);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                WindowsElement FilePage = session.FindElementByName(file);
                Actions actions = new Actions(session);
                actions.DoubleClick(FilePage).Build().Perform();
                Thread.Sleep(3000);                
            }

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you write the actions like this?

```
action.KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys("N").KeyUp(Keys.Alt).SendKeys("19th December 1932 (2).xlsx")Perform();
action.KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys("o").KeyUp(Keys.Alt).Perform();
```

Comment: Thi is not work. Type "string".
Actions KeyDown(string theKey);